# Is it possible to attach a Remote Event Receiver to my lists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

Is it possible to attach a Remote Event Receiver to my existing list in my site, and not to the list in my app? I'm guessing no as I can't find anything on this, and I think this would potentially 'hurt' SharePoint.

If I need to get this to work, I need to look at a sandbox or farm solution right?

TIA

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say not possible to attach an Remote Event Receiver to a list in the Host-web, because these are actually Cross site-collections.

In the Host web you would only be able to deploy regular event receivers (targeting a class in an assembly) and the Remote event receivers take the URL of the actual WCF as the target, which wouldn't exist in the Host-web anyways:

```
<Url>~remoteAppUrl/RemoteEventReceiver1.svc</Url>
```

or

```
<Url>http://apps.mydomain.com:36511/MyReR.svc</Url>
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I thought, just wanted a second opinion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
Just handle the event receiver while installing the app by changing the property attribute to true as sown below.

[image]

And then just write the following code

```
public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

            switch (properties.EventType)
            {
                case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
                    HandleAppInstalled(properties);
                    break;
                case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded:
                    HandleItemAdded(properties);
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void HandleAppInstalled(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext =
                      TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    List myList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List Name");
                    clientContext.Load(myList, p => p.EventReceivers);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    bool rerExists = false;

                    foreach (var rer in myList.EventReceivers)
                    {
                        if (rer.ReceiverName == "ItemAddedEvent")
                        {
                            rerExists = true;
                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Found existing ItemAdded receiver at "
                               + rer.ReceiverUrl);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!rerExists)
                    {
                        EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver =new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                        receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdded;


                        receiver.ReceiverUrl = "Your service url";
                        receiver.ReceiverName = "ItemAddedEvent";
                        receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                        myList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added ItemAdded receiver at " + msg.Headers.To.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 private void HandleItemAdded(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext =
              TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
            {
                if (clientContext != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        List photos = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your List Name");
                        ListItem item = photos.GetItemById(
                           properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
                        clientContext.Load(item);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        item["Title"] += "\nUpdated by RER " +
                             System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                        item.Update();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception oops)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(oops.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I forgot to remove some code. Just remove the "+ msg.Headers.To.ToString()" portion from the code.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I actually used the ItemAdding event from an Appweb List instead of AppInstalling

Answer (score 0):

IT is possible only programmaticly but it does not work if you deploy.

```
var eventReceiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation
                     {
                         EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemAdding,
                         ReceiverAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
                         ReceiverClass = "RemoteReciverWeb.Services.ContactAddEventReceiver",
                         ReceiverName = "ContactAddEventReceiver",
                         ReceiverUrl = remoteEventEndPointUrl,
                         SequenceNumber = 1000
                     };

clientContext.Load(eventresevers);
```